# Start capacitor size

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

Looking for some advice. My Trane A/C 5 ton outside unit has provisions for the Trane BAYKSKT252A start assist kit. This appears to be a standard 5-2-1 start capacitor, so I got a 5-2-1 4-5 ton kit, and looking at a picture of the kit it’s using a 135-162 MFD capacitor, where the 5-2-1 is using a 270-324MFD capacitor. Is this going to be a problem if I install the 5-2-1?

Comment: I would not use the larger cap. The capacitive reactance is matched to the inductive reactance . using a value way outside the nominal value can cause more problems.

Comment: Starter kit/ capacitor problems often mean a compressor is failing. I am there myself;over the last few months I have had these units replaced and now the service guy says it is not worth replacing them again. My 5 ton is about 14 years old.

Comment: The compressor itself ohms out correctly and isn’t drawing RLA. It blew a 17 year old run capacitor at the start of the season and after replacement runs fine, I figured adding the start kit would help it live somewhat longer with the reduced inrush. Just hedging bets, I’m probably in for a new system in the next couple of years anyway. Thanks all,